# How to get add certificate in provisioning profile in company account

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I worked for a company, and my company has a apple company account and one person used to maintain provisioning profile and certificated for all the developers. I created a new certificate through xcode using my apple id provided my company which is linked to company apple account. After creating account all provisioning profiles validate again so that they have all newly crated certificate.

But still xcode giving me error 'certificate doesn't have provisions profile'. Now i am not sure what else to do. That guy has no clue why it is happening. Does he need to click somewhere in company account to get the certificate validated for the provisioning profile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are you using xcode 8 just check Automatically manage signing and select you team xcode will do it. Otherwise create/edit your desire Provisioning Profile and select all available certificate and download and double tap that Provisioning Profile to run on you mac.

Comment: 'Provisioning Profile and select all available certificate and download and double tap that Provisioning Profile to run on you mac.' This does seem useful. Thanks.